# show next record of sqlite database in textview by swiping

Tags: android, sqlite, textview

I have an SQLite external database. There is a TextView to display the record of the database. There is no problem in getting and showing the data in this TextView. Now I want to do something else. When a user swipes the TextView, I want the next record to be displayed in the TextView. And when the user swipes back, the previous record is displayed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you need to create a custom view that extends the TextView base class.

```
class SwipeableTextView extends TextView {
    //here is three constructors from View class
    public SwipeableTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SwipeableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SwipeableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
class MainActivity {

    int startX,
    starty = 0;

    //inside onCreate
    TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.myTextView)
    tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //called when you touch view
                startx = event.x;
                starty = event.y;
                return true;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: //when you lift up your finger from viev
                return true;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: //when you finger on view
                int differenceX,
                differenceY;
                differenceX = startX - event.x;

                if (Math.abs(differenceX) > 50)
                changeTextMethod();

                return true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you. but what is this method changeTextMethod();?

Comment: This is your custom method where you cfn write your interaction with the DB and change text, I wrote this line of code for example. Does it works?